# Remove 3D geometry in shapefile using OGR

Tags: shapefile, ogr, 3d

I have a series of shapefiles, that have 3D geometries (ie: points ZM). I would like to remove the 3D geometry so that the files are 2D. Is there a way to remove 3D geometry from a shapefile using OGR?

Comment: Technically, shapefiles with elevation values and measures are 4-D, not 3-D.

Comment: Is it enough to update Z and M to zero or do you want that the type of the shapefile is changed into POINT?

Comment: My preference would be to have the geometry as a point, not a pointZM

Comment: Then simply write a new shapefile as `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_2d.shp input_zm.shp -dim 2` http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. However, I do not know if it works if you really has POINTZM shapefile because GDAL does not support M http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html. Let's hope it just skips M values.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if the -dim was referencing geometry

Comment: It worked. You should move your comment over to an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write your data into a new shapefile with ogr2ogr and force geometry type into 2D with the -dim switch.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output_2d.shp input_zm.shp -dim 2
```

The -dim setting is not limited to shapefiles but works in the same way for most vector formats. One exception I know is Oracle Spatial that does not honour the ogr2ogr switch but you must use the layer specific `-lco DIM=2`instead.

http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html

Answer (score 3):

Once your shapefile is read as `ogr.Geometry`, you can use its `flattenTo2d()` method.

See the [GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#aaae1a2ced937a5900b2bfeb717bad6c9).