# Using QGIS to edit shapefile without creating 3D shape types

Tags: qgis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I have edited a shapefile with QGIS where I have *cut* some polygons to get open lines. The original file works in my application, whereas the edited one does not. I'd like to understand what's going on and how I can fix it.

The problem shows up when reading in the edited shapefile with the `Basemap.readshapefile` function. It raises the following error:

```
ValueError: readshapefile can only handle 2D shape types
```

I have seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417764/basemap-readshapefile-valueerror) where they point that this is a a problem with 3D objects not being understood by the library. In [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255540/convert-3d-shapefile-to-2d-in-qgis) it is explained how to save as 2D object with QGIS. I have tried not marking the z coordinate when saving but it does not work.

For more details, I have obtained some metadata with `ogrinfo -al`. The original file I have, which is understood by `Basemap.readshapefile` looks like this:

```
INFO: Open of `original.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: original
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 182
Extent: (-1004337.328188, 3131929.504592) - (1127031.464626, 4859263.795340)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 30N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-3,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",32630]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
COD_Z: String (7.0)
NOM_Z: String (50.0)
COD_PROV: String (4.0)
NOM_PROV: String (50.0)
COD_CCAA: String (2.0)
NOM_CCAA: String (50.0)
OGRFeature(AEMET-meteoalerta-v6-zonas-32630):0
  COD_Z (String) = 610401
  NOM_Z (String) = Valle del Almanzora y Los Vélez
  COD_PROV (String) = 6104
  NOM_PROV (String) = Almería
  COD_CCAA (String) = 61
  NOM_CCAA (String) = Andalucía
  POLYGON ((530809.950806814 4131852.23056696,530731.953526206 4132794.1983588,531421.930050147
[...]
```

As I mentioned, my edit consists of changing the polygons to lines and then cutting some of them. I have saved the shape making sure the z coordinate is not saved. This is the metadata of the shapefile:

```
INFO: Open of `new.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: new
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2023-11-29
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 459
Extent: (-17.926608, 0.000000) - (3.437484, 43.743597)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
COD_Z: String (7.0)
NOM_Z: String (50.0)
COD_PROV: String (4.0)
NOM_PROV: String (50.0)
COD_CCAA: String (2.0)
NOM_CCAA: String (50.0)
OGRFeature(zonas3):0
  COD_Z (String) = 691703
  NOM_Z (String) = Ampurdán
  COD_PROV (String) = 6917
  NOM_PROV (String) = Girona
  COD_CCAA (String) = 69
  NOM_CCAA (String) = Cataluña

OGRFeature(zonas3):1
  COD_Z (String) = 691703
  NOM_Z (String) = Ampurdán
  COD_PROV (String) = 6917
  NOM_PROV (String) = Girona
  COD_CCAA (String) = 69
  NOM_CCAA (String) = Cataluña
  LINESTRING (3.08207331360263 41.8248262810634,3.07629926554 
[...]
```

The major difference is the `Geometry: Line String` or `Geometry: Polygon`.

If this is the source of the problem, how can I save this file, which can be read nicely by QGIS, without Z information so it can be read by `Basemap.readshapefile`?

Comment: Yes, I suspect the problem is that the working file has polyons (considered 2D) and the other has iine(strings) that are considered to be 1D (as opposed to points which are 0D) as opposed to the the other meaning of 3D (with a Z value) which is what your linked questions are dealing with

Comment: Could it be that your application expect polygon and don't accept line ?

Comment: Unsure if the problems is with polygons or lines but you can convert polygonZ and PolylineZ to remove the Z with ogr2ogr.  A simple command line call would do the trick.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166523/remove-3d-geometry-in-shapefile-using-ogr

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Eventually and after some tests, the problem seems to be that some of the features has no data due to the way I delete the lines... I do not really understand, so I have posted a different question with the details I have so far:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471340/clearing-some-lines-in-qgis-leads-to-features-with-no-data