# Clearing some lines in QGIS leads to features with no data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to cut and delete some lines in a shapefile with QGIS. The output of this edit is the input to the `Basemap.readshapefile` function in matplotlib.

My edited shapefile does not work well. It complains about this: `ValueError: readshapefile can only handle a single shape type per file`

After many trials and some research, I noticed using the `ogrinfo` tool that the problem might be these "dataless" features (I attach a screenshot with vimdiff between the raw shp file and the edited one):

[image]

There are some features that lack the `LINESTRING` data. How can I delete these features all together? Currently I'm just select the line by selection all the nodes with the vertex tool and then deleting the nodes.

Comment: How do you go about deleting features from your dataset?

Comment: I select the features with the vertex tool and then I delete the nodes. I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: That will not delete the feature. It deletes the feature's geometry only. The feature will still exist with a null geometry. To delete a feature completely, first select it and then delete it.

Comment: OK, dump question... how do I select a feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the vertex tool to delete feature vertices will not delete the feature. It deletes the feature's geometry only. It will no longer appear on the map canvas, however, the feature will still exist with a null geometry.

To delete a feature completely, first select it and then delete it.

There are various ways to make selections, including:

The **Selection Toolbar** (View > Toolbars > Selection Toolbar):

[image]

The **Select by expression tool** (*Processing toolbox > Vector Selection > Select by expression*)
with an expression such as:

[image]

```
code = 'A' or code in ('C', 'D')
```

Where `code` is a field name and the letters represent attribute values you are interested in.

[image]

Here the selected features are coloured yellow.

Comment: Alternatively, if one can't come up with an easy data-driven rule by which to select features, one can select feature by clicking on the or drawing a frame around them using the left-most tool of the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem I was facing.